# Convert Hex string of high length to decimal

Tags: c, numbers, hex, decimal, number-formatting

I'm trying to write a function that can convert a seriesof uint_8 values (set in an array) into one single Decimal number and print it.
The values get parsed in an array of known, but not constant length len:

```
void print_decimal(size_t len, uint8_t buf[len]);
```

Buf is ordered, so that the most significant digits of the resulting decimal number are at the front of the array, f.e.:
-> buf[0] = 1111 1111; buf[1] = 0000 0000 -> Result: 0xFF00 -> Convert to decimal

The issue is, that the length / size of the resulting number exceeds the size of a single cariable like uint64_t (or even 128 Bit types), so simply converting it is not an option.

Are there any smart and easy ways to convert this? F.e. digitwise through an algorithm?

Comment: Have you tried the suggestion put forward when you [asked this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73006939/print-uint-8t-array-hex-array-as-decimal-number) a couple of hours ago? The "digitwise through an algorithm" was put forward there.

Comment: @WeatherVane I've tried it, yes but that raises multiple questions (depending on how I do it):
- How do you convert it digitwise? I've tried it, lets take 0xBBB as an example, the last B touces all the other digits aswell, so we got 11 + 176 + 16*176
- If I were to use the addition as I wrote above, I'd have to somehow add and Multiply those numbers, which exceed any datatype
If I were to use a self-made datatype, that would make it possible, but this is an alternative that creates a hige overhead for a simple problem -> Hence this question about a simple way

Comment: Then please post the attempted solution, and state what problems you are having

Comment: Please show the code, in the question, not in comments. I described a fairly simple way, how are you getting on with it? Have you searched for previous questions which discuss how to do it?

Comment: There is no code, my idea of digitwise already fails on paper, and I didn't find an algorithm that allows the conversion without calculating and adding every single hexDigit * 16^position 
(Here position equals the position in the hex number read from the right starting at 0, so in f.e. 0xA00 the position of A is 2)

Comment: I'll go over the algorithm again. Do a 'longhand' division of each array element by 10, as you would with pencil and paper. The remainder is the least significant digit of the output. Repeat until all the elements of the input array are 0.

Comment: Divide by 10 and then? If we take 0xBBB again, can you give me a short example of how to do it? (The result is 3003 by the way). The issue is: how do you handle the transfer since we aren't in bas 10 anymore, I can't just add it onto the next number and move one digit up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an example of the repeated division by 0x0A using 'longhand'

```
      1 2C
    ------
0A ) 0B BB
     0A
    ---
      1 BB
      1 B8
     -----
         3  l.s. digit
```

Repeat

```
      0 1E
    ------
0A ) 01 2C
     00
    ---
      1 2C
      1 2C
     -----
         0 next l.s. digit
```

Repeat

```
      0 03
    ------
0A ) 00 1E
     00
    ---
      0 1E
      0 1E
     -----
         0 next l.s. digit
```

Repeat

```
      0 00
    ------
0A ) 00 03
     00 
    ---
      0 03
      0 00
     -----
         3 m.s. digit
```

Result of the string of remainders is `3003` which is decimal of `0xBBB`.

Note that we were never "in base ten". The division was by ten, but the only decimals are the digits that fall out with each repetition.

Comment: Thank you, that seems reaonable. After watching / reading multiple tutorials on longhand division, I have one question tough: How do you get the 3 on the first step?

Comment: It is the remainder from the division by ten, as in every step. `1bb - 1b8`

Comment: Oh damn, my bad. I read it as 1BB and was wondering for way too long! Thenks a lot. I will try to code it and then mark it as the answer if it works

Comment: I guessed that, which was why I put that in lower case! Note that you'll need to work with a 'running' value. After each division you shift it left by 8 bits and add the next byte. Like you would when doing it on paper. In the first set of divisions, that takes the value `b` and then `1bb` and then `3`.